# Finite differences as a variational method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, variational-principle

I think I should be able to derive finite differences for the Schroedinger equation by starting from a variational method. More specifically: in finite differences we approximate

$$\{\psi(x),x\in\mathbb{R}\}\approx\{\psi(x_n),x_n=n\Delta x, n\in\{0,\dots,N-1\}\}$$

but $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$, hence, calling $\psi(x_n)=:\psi_n$

$$|\phi\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\psi_n|x_n\rangle $$

is the vector that corresponds to our approximate wavefunction. If I try to use the variational principle by optimizing the coefficients $\psi_n$, I expect to fall back onto something similar to finite differences.

We want to minimize

$$E^*=\frac{\langle \phi|H|\phi\rangle}{\langle \phi|\phi\rangle} $$

The denominator is easy $$\langle \phi|\phi\rangle=\sum_n |\psi_n|^2$$

the numerator is trickier: infringing every known rule of reasonable mathematics we can calculate

$$\langle x_m|\hat{p}^2|x_n\rangle=\int dp dp' \langle x_m|p\rangle\langle p|pp'|p'\rangle\langle p'|x_n\rangle=\int dp e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}(x_n-x_m)}p^2=
\\ -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\int dp e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}(x-x_m)}\big|_{x=x_n}=-\hbar^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\delta(x-x_m)\big|_{x=x_n}:=-\hbar^2 \delta ''(x_n-x_m)$$

setting aside whether this expression means anything at all

$$E^*=\frac{1}{\sum_n |\psi_n|^2}\left(-\hbar^2\sum_{m,n}\psi_n\psi_m^*\delta''(x_n-x_m)+\sum_n V(x_n)|\psi_n|^2\right) $$

I doubt this is the right approach, what can I do? Differentiating this doesn't give anything meaningful, and the problem is those momentum matrix elements. Is this idea completely ill defined?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator

Comment: @Nephente I don't understand what you mean, I know how to do finite differences, I was just wondering if one could derive it from a variational principle without explicitely discretizing the laplacian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96896/discussion-between-user2723984-and-lux).